# Is there a compact way to specify solid per-triangle colors when using Vertex Buffer Objects?

Tags: iphone, performance, opengl-es

I'm drawing a VBO in GL_TRIANGLES mode, and I just draw solid triangles.

Right now I have to create a 4-component color for every single vertex. For each triangle that means 3 colors, which results in a massive amount of 12 values. But all I need is a solid color for the triangle.

Is there a way of "compressing" this amount of data so that -at least in memory- there are just 4 values stored to define the color of a triangle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can call `glColor*` before you render your triangle. It sets the "current" vertex color, and then you don't need to bother with colors per-vertex.

Comment: I'm using VBOs so glColor is no option, unfortunately.

Comment: @openfrog - Are you using OpenGL ES 1.1 or 2.0? If 1.1, I think `glColor*` should still be fine if you don't specify color in your vertex format.

Answer (score 0):

If its an rgb color you should be able to store it as a
 single int

Each byte in the int represents a color argb.

You could choose to use the alpha channel or ignore it

Comment: Would this solve the problem of having to duplicate color information 3 times per triangle? Can you give an example?

Comment: You would still need an int for each corner if they aren't going to be the same color.

Comment: An example would be very helpful!

Comment: are you using something like glcolorpointer ? for your values instead of using an int, you could use 3 bytes and get the result you are looking for, you would only handle it for every 3rd vertex.